# Does the Tree of Souls on Pandora see the future?

Tags: avatar, souls

How did the woodsprites (atokirina') or seed of the tree of souls know that Jake Sully was so important?

The Tree of Souls (Vitraya Ramunong) is the connection to Eywa and the ancestor's. Ie messages from the past could be possible. But the future?

I understand Eywa "is a deity, a goddess. Made up of all living things. Everything they know". So possibly can see/know the future. But the tree of souls and the little seeds are methods for the *ancestor's* to pass messages to the Na'vi of Pandora.

How do the dead see the future? Or is it the dead seeing the future through Eywa and then passing on a message to the living?

Answer (score 5):

### There's no good evidence to suggest that Eywa is a *supernatural* being. She/it may well be *intelligent* though.

Grace Augustine's theory (and one backed up by the events of the film) is that Eywa is a **pan-planetary hivemind**, utilising the Tree of Souls and the Tree of Voices to communicate directly with the Na'vi and connecting the living creatures of Pandora in a very real, physical sense. This manifests in it acting as a sort of planetary controller, ensuring that the ecology remains in harmony.

When it senses that the human interlopers have sent a suitable emissary, Jake, it attempts to communicate by sending its [seeds](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Woodsprite) (which may or may not be under Eywa's *direct* control) to guide him to the nearest helpful Na'vi who can teach him their ways. This then serves as a precursor to inducting him into their mystic religion and, more importantly, **preparing him to interface with Eywa**. When that goes wrong, Eywa then directs the lifeforms at her disposal to attack the humans, resulting in a massive [zerg rush](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zerg-rush).